# Как генерировать (обновлять) токен Dropbox api?

Tags: php, dropbox-api

Каким образом можно обновлять или генерировать токен api dropbox, если токен истек ?

Использую библиотеку https://github.com/spatie/dropbox-api для работы с api через php

Мои попытки:

1. Искал инфу в гугле, практически ничего не нашел, а из того, что я
   нашел, мне не помогло. Например метод refresh - так как в актуальной
   версии библиотеки spatie нет этого метода.
2. Читал документацию не нашел как обновлять токен автоматически
3. Задал вопрос chat gpt - не дал внятного ответа
4. И вот наконец задал вопрос на stackoverflow

Единственный вариант который я знаю, это в ручную проверять и обновлять если истек, но этот вариант мне не подходит

```
    <?php 
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/vendor/autoload.php';
    
    use Spatie\Dropbox\Client as DropboxClient;
    
    $appKey = '0cn********4kt5g';
    $appSecret =  'tek*********ri9n';
    $token = 'sl.B****************************7LH6zm7hfUImY4A2bNu4RTGK9Oh5nmy6J2qfO8EQ2J63MSZ-1EmIUtR0MQvfJrSXU4AKY9i4U_8sTb1WNatpbB8ezi-iT4rhKVLAgKMNvfmY';
    
    $client = new DropboxClient($token);
    
    $dbx->upload('/filename.txt', file_get_contents('file.txt'), $mode='add');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы внимательно прочитали документацию? https://github.com/spatie/dropbox-api

Comment: В библиотеке на Python не припоминаю проблем с этим. А любую библиотеку можно разложить на REST повторить.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел, следуй инструкции. Официальная поддержка dropbox

https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/Get-refresh-token-from-access-token/m-p/596755#M27728

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Эту задачу делегировал Вам, не благодарите 

Answer (score -3):

1. [Тут скрин того что получилось найти](https://imgur.com/a/EYaoUMb). 
   [Сам запрос к гуглу](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20refresh%20dropbox%20token&oq=how%20to%20refresh%20dropbox%20token&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIICAEQABgWGB7SAQkxMDkyMGowajSoAgCwAgA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). 
   [Первая ссылка в гугле](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide#:%7E:text=To%20update%20your%20access%20token,is%20easier%20with%20an%20SDK.).

**Краткая выжимка:**

> When using refresh tokens, your call to the /oauth2/token endpoint
> with the grant_type of authorization_code will return a short-lived
> access token and a refresh token, which should be securely stored.
>
> Note: you’ll need to include token_access_type=offline as a parameter
> on your Authorization URL in order to return a refresh_token inside
> your access token payload. To update your access token, call the
> /oauth2/token endpoint - specifying your refresh_token as a parameter
> and using the grant_type of refresh_token. The endpoint will return a
> new short-lived access token and a timestamp indicating its expiration
> time.

**Deepl Перевод:**

> При использовании маркеров обновления вызов конечной точки
> /oauth2/token с типом grant_type авторизации authorization_code
> возвращает недолговечный маркер доступа и маркер обновления, которые
> должны надежно храниться.
>
> Примечание: чтобы вернуть refresh_token внутри полезной нагрузки
> токена доступа, необходимо в качестве параметра авторизационного URL
> указать token_access_type=offline. Чтобы обновить маркер доступа,
> вызовите конечную точку /oauth2/token, указав в качестве параметра
> refresh_token и используя grant_type refresh_token. Конечная точка
> вернет новый короткоживущий токен доступа и временную метку,
> указывающую на время его действия.

2. /oauth2/token [Документация](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-token)
3. ChatGPT - клёвая штука, надеюсь скоро сделают 5 версию и можно будет вообще не писать самому код) Но иногда он хорошо помогает.

P.S. Если в используемой Вами библиотеке нет нужного метода, можно исследовать её на возможность применения кастомных запросов, а не уже готовых. Или на крайний случай - можно форкнуть, залить в https://packagist.org/ свою версию, и использовать её. Но тогда нужно будет мониторить родительскую репу, чтобы сливать в свою репу изменения. Ещё вариант - написать issue с типом feature, и предложить создателю добавить недостающий функционал.

P.P.S. В репозитории https://github.com/spatie/dropbox-api при поиске на странице AutoRefreshingDropBoxTokenService

```php
// implements Spatie\Dropbox\TokenProvider
$tokenProvider = new AutoRefreshingDropBoxTokenService($refreshToken);
$client = new Spatie\Dropbox\Client($tokenProvider);
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/876637)

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: @NowhereMan Исправил.